# How to use a Item loader in my Scrapy spider code?

Tags: python, json, xpath, scrapy

I've slowly created the following (working) Scrapy spider that retrieves news articles and some other data from a news website. The problem I have is that there is a lot of whitespace in one of the items. I found in the Scrapy help file and on stackoverflow ([How To Remove White Space in Scrapy Spider Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041158/how-to-remove-white-space-in-scrapy-spider-data)) that I should use a Item loader. I have no idea how to integrate the item loader in my existing code. This code evolved from the standard scraper from the Scrapy tutorial. To me the code related to the Item loader is very hard to combine with what was explained in the tutorial.

```
import scrapy
from datetime import timedelta, date
from nos.items import NosItem


def daterange(start_date, end_date):
        for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
            yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2015, 8, 19)
end_date = date(2015, 8, 20)
nos_urls = []
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    nos_urls.append(single_date.strftime("http://nos.nl/nieuws/archief/%Y-%m-%d"))


class NosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nos"
    allowed_domains = ["nos.nl"]

    start_urls = nos_urls

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="archief"]/ul/li'):
            item = NosItem()
            item['name'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()[0]
            item['date'] = sel.xpath('a/div[1]/time/@datetime').extract()[0]
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('a/div[@class="list-time__title link-hover"]/text()').extract()[0]
            url = response.urljoin(item['name'])
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request


    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/article'):
            item = response.meta['item']
            textdata = sel.xpath('section//text()').extract()
            textdata = " ".join(textdata)
            #textdata = textdata.replace("\n", "")
            #textdata = textdata.strip(' \t\n\r\\n')
            item['article'] = textdata
            yield item
```

This is a example of the JSON export that I get at the moment:

```
{"date": "2015-08-19T15:43:26+0200", "article": "\n        Man met bijl aangehouden \n        \n         \n          De man zou zijn vrouw hebben aangevallen met een bijl en dreigde zichzelf iets aan te doen.\n         Video afspelen \n                              00:34\n                         De politie heeft in Schijndel een man aangehouden die verdacht wordt van huiselijk geweld. De man had zichzelf in een woning opgesloten en dreigde zichzelf iets aan te doen. [text cut off]", "name": "/artikel/2052794-politie-in-schijndel-heeft-handen-vol-aan-verdachte-huiselijk-geweld.html", "desc": "Politie in Schijndel heeft handen vol aan verdachte huiselijk geweld"}
```

The article item cointains the whitespace and also many \n that I would like to remove.

I believe these functions would help solve the problem:

```
l.default_input_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.split(), replace_escape_chars)
l.default_output_processor = Join()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use just `unicode.strip()` in your extraction:

```
textdata = " ".join(map(unicode.strip,textdata))
```

This removes all the whitespace from your data and you get the article contents cleaner.

Comment: The result looks somehow odd to me `         M a n  m e t  b i j l  a a n g e h o u d e n ` (...) ;-)

Comment: well, if your `textdata` is just a string and not an array of strings then the `" ".join` method inserts the space between the characters. You have to look at this too of course. I've used your spider and there I get arrays of strings back -- not a single string.

Comment: For me this answer seems to work perfectly, it even escapes quotes in the string with \" which is nice :-). I also made a custom pipeline to get my JSON export in utf-8, would using unicode.strip negate the need for the custom pipeline?

Comment: @GHajba That's really embarrassing for me ... I really need a break and a cup of coffee.